# Updating the database using the value which is stored in variable

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using Visual C# 2010 express windows form application & Mysql for DB.
I want to get a value (current no of students) from DB and increase it by 1 and update that value. for that I use the below code, but I'm getting an error called "unknown column 'x' in 'field list'.

```
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT NoOfStudents FROM batch", connection);
                MySqlDataReader dr = null;
                dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                int x;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                x = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                x = x + 1;
               }
                dr.Close();
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE batch SET NoOfStudents= x", connection);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
string sql=string.Format("UPDATE batch SET NoOfStudents= {0}",x);
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
```

x is a variable declared in your program and Mysql dont know any thing about it, this is just a string and its content is ignored by the compiler

Comment: still it showing an error called "use of unassigned local variable 'x'. Am I assigned x wrongly???

Comment: @user1724557 you should initialize x for something, ex: int x=0;and then if(x!=0) then execute the query

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE batch SET NoOfStudents= {0}",x), connection);
```