# OdbcDataReader Overwriting

Tags: c#, mysql, odbcdatareader

I seem to be having problems with my method that will return an Integer. I am attempting to modify the rows of a particular column with this returning Integer. The database will update the pre-existing column values with this new returned value. However, it appears that every row is being modified to the LAST row's value, regardless of what the specific row held previously. I am sure my code is just overwriting the variable, but I am wondering where. Here is my method; would appreciate feedback.

```
private int extractValue()
{
  if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   { 
     this.connection.Open();
   }
   ParsingHelper helper = null // different class - no issues with this.
   String query = "SELECT device FROM dLogger";
   OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, this.connection);
   List<Int32> list = new List<Int32>();
   OdbcDataReader reader = null;
   reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
      {
        helper = new ParsingHelper();
        helper.assemble(list[i]);
      }
     }
    return helper.getFirst();
   }
```

No problem with the ParsingHelper here, it does the correct work. My problem is the overwriting. I thought a List would alleviate this issue but I am missing something, evidently.

EDIT: Would this approach work better?

```
while(reader.Read())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
     list.Add(reader.GetInt32(i));
     //....
    }
```

If my table originally looked like this:

```
   ColA
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

And my function, for example, multiplied each number by 2. The new column would look like

```
 ColA
  8 // rather than 2
  8 // rather than 4
  8 // rather than 6
  8 // 8 is the last value - therefore, correct.
```

So you see, I am running into some overwriting issues here. It appears the reader will read effectively and to the last row but it is not modifying values correctly, it is only assigning each value to the last value.

EDIT:
Here is where I am updating my database:

```
private void update() 
{
 String query = "UPDATE dLogger SET device = ?";
 OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, this.connection);
 if (this.connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   {
     this.connection.Open();
    }
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", extractValue());
  }
```

Also, here is my simple Parsing Helper Class assemble()

```
  private void assemble(int value)
  {
   setFirst(value);
  }

  private void setFirst(int value)
  {
    value = value * 2;
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. I see no code updating anything. You're constructing a list of numbers and then returning the first number in your list.

Comment: My fault. I want to read through the entire column's values. Add these values to the list. For each member of the list, I want to pass the member to a function. I will provide an edit with an approach that I might try.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired result

Comment: Sure, I added some relevant table information.

Comment: But you have no code doing any modification at all. Also, is your desired result that all columns have the value 8?

Comment: The desired output is each column does not have the same value. This will do the modification: helper.assemble(list[i]);
This method is called on in another method that actually updates the database. The method itself works perfectly fine. I didn't post it because of that. The root problem is the overwriting.

Comment: But you have no code doing any modification at all!

Comment: I edited my response above.

Comment: Please show the helper.assemble method.

Comment: Ok, I added the other method and portions of the other class. The update() method gets called in another query. "SELECT '" + update + "' AS device FROM dLogger";

Comment: But it does nothing, unless I'm missing something. You are not returning anything from your methods. They change the value and then discard it.

Comment: I don't know how much code you have, but maybe you should consider showing more. Is anything ever changed in your database?

Comment: Yes, the database gets changed every time I run the application. However, the values are ALL changed to the last row's value. The sample table I posted in my edit is the output when I run the program (the repeating 8's is what I get but the different values is what I want). The last row will overwrite all of the rows. The loop is suppose to modify a row, move to the next, modify that, move to the next. Each value is independent of each other but my code is not doing that.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code in its entirety, but you seem to be using an update without a where and thus changing every row every time you update.

Comment: But I DO want every row updated. I want every existing row to be updated with my method. The problem is the overwriting. If there were 3 rows, each value updated would be the actual value of the third row. It's just reassigning the value rather than iterating through and assigning one by one.

Comment: I wanted something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194804/updating-the-database-using-the-value-which-is-stored-in-variable

Answer (score 0):

Just change your

```
String query = "SELECT device FROM dLogger";
```

to

```
String query = "UPDATE dLogger SET device=device*2";
```

thus:

```
private void extractValue()
{
  if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   { 
     this.connection.Open();
   }
   String query = "UPDATE dLogger SET device=device*2";
   OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, this.connection);
   command.Execute();
}
```